# maven pass command argument at build time to overwrite property

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

In our application, we have a system to whitelabel.

in `application.properties` there is a setting `theme=default`

this setting is injected into a Spring managed bean, which then does manipulation of the app through the framework, like adding the correct css, etc

what I would like to be able to do, is at build time (war creation), specify the theme, eg `mvn clean install -theme:some-theme`. this would then update `application.properties`, and modify `theme`
and if you run just `mvn clean install` then `theme=default` or `unmodified`

is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to set a property via command-line is using `-D`:

```
mvn -Dproperty=value clean package
```

It will **overwrite** any property previously defined in the `pom.xml`.

---

So if you have in your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <theme>myDefaultTheme</theme>
</properties>
```

`mvn -Dtheme=halloween clean package` would overwrite `theme`s value during this execution, having the effect as if you had:

```
<properties>
    <theme>halloween</theme>
</properties>
```

Comment: this combined with resource filtering is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are looking for is maven build profiles and [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). You can assign each theme a profile and on the basis of profile, you can change the value of parameters in application.properties

e.g.

```
<build>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>white</id>
        <properties>
            <theme>white</theme>
            <prop1>xyz</prop1>
            <!--and some other properties-->
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <properties>
            <theme>default</theme>
            <prop1>abc</prop1>
            <!--and some other properties-->
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And you can have a properties file located in src/main/resources:

application.properties:

```
my.theme=${theme}
my.custom.property=${prop1}
```

This approach gives the flexibility of doing customization based on the the profile, so can say that bulk customizations.